# Edges not following the mesh in edit mode?

Tags: modifiers, edges, subdivision-surface

Maya user moving to blender, not sure why my edges are being overlapped by the surfaces instead of following them.

[image]

Object mode displays the edges the way I would prefer to edit them.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119802/behavior-on-adjust-edit-cage-subsurf  @MrZak or wait for some desperado to answer lol.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [subdivision surface modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html) on your mesh. By default that modifier does not change the display of the original mesh while in edit mode. Its personal preference I like to see the original mesh most of the time, but coming from max I can see why you want the edges on the mesh.

Just head to the *Properties* window, then the *Modifiers* tab and look a the  *Subdivision* modifier (*Subsurf* modifier in versions prior to 2.8).  Then simply tick the button highlighted in red "Adjust edit cage to modifier result."

[image: Subdivision modifier]